# Sort array in Scala partially

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting

How can I sort a region in an array in Scala?

I have an array, say `var DivA = new Array[Int](100005)`.

I filled the elements in `DivA` up to some position which is less than 100005.
For example my array looks like `Diva = {1,2,10,5,15,20}`.

In C++ we have `sort(DivA, DivA + N)`, but how can we sort arrays in Scala up to a certain index?

I tried `Sorting.quickSort(DivA)`, but I don't know how to define the index up to which I want to sort the array, so that the statement above sorts the array, and the array looks like `DivA={0,0,0,0,0}`?

```
      var Diva=new Array[Int](10000);
      for(j<-15 to 0 by -1){
           DivA(posA)=j;
           posA=posA+1;
      }
      Sorting.quickSort(DivA);

      for(j<-0 to posA-1)
        {
          print(DivA(j));
          print(" ");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort a region in an array, you can use the `sort` method in `java.util.Arrays`:

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(DivA, 0, 15)
```

this method offers `fromIndex` and `toIndex`. Note that this method sorts *in place*. That's probably OK in your case, as the style you apply seems to be "imperative".

If performance matters, arrays will probably be faster than other collections. Other reasons for using arrays might be memory consumption or interoperability.

Otherwise you can probably design your data structures/algorithm in a different (more "functional") way by using idiomatic Scala collections.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` or `sortBy`, depending on your needs. In case of simple `Array[Int]`, `sorted` should be enough:

```
val arr = Array.iterate(15, 15)(_ - 1)
arr: Array[Int] = Array(15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

val sortedArray = arr.sorted
sortedArray: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
```

You can provide your own `Ordering` typeclass if you want some other kind of order.

You can find it in the [documentation.](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Array)

Although, as was noted in other answer, you should prefer immutable `Vector` unless you have good reason to switch to `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

`sorted()` method is common for all collections, and Arrays in Scala are implicitly converted to a collection.
So you can call sorted on `Array[Int]`, eg:

```
scala> val p = (10 to 1 by -1).toArray
p: Array[Int] = Array(10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

scala> p.sorted
res5: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are programming in Scala, you should think about Vector or List because those are immutable which is prefferd way of programming in Scala...

And for Vector and List there is sorted() function which sorts an array

Comment: i read about list and vector but is there no any way to sort array of integer ?